# Cannot Import internal modules in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, project-structure

I have created internal modules which follow the structure such as follows-

```
project
└── src
    └── rogers
          └──__init__.py
          └── cd
            ├── __init__.py
            ├── preprocessor
            └── dataOps
                   └── __init__.py
                   └── verint.py
```

The error I get -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_scripts/PreprocessingStep/verint_preprocessing.py", line 11, in <module>
    from rogers.cd.dataOPs import Verint
ImportError: No module named rogers.cd.dataOPs
```

The **init**.py in the dataops looks like this

```
from rogers.cd.dataOPs.boldchat import *
from rogers.cd.dataOPs.verint import *
```

This is what my setup.py looks like (not showing the entire file, only part of it)

```
classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    install_requires = external_packages,
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    packages=  setuptools.find_namespace_packages(where="src"),
    package_data={'': ['*.yaml']},
    include_package_data=True,
    python_requires=">=3.7",
```

I recently migrated from PyCharm to VSCode. The code was running fine in PyCharm but doesn't work for VSCode.

Comment: `Rogers` is missing the `__init__.py` so it wouldn't be a package. You don't say if you've installed the package and activated the venv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setup.py does not work in VSCode, you can modify the PYTHONPATH in VSCode through `(terminal.integrated.env.*) and/or within an .env file`:

> The PYTHONPATH environment variable specifies additional locations
> where the Python interpreter should look for modules. In VS Code,
> PYTHONPATH can be set through the terminal settings
> (terminal.integrated.env.*) and/or within an .env file.
>
> When the terminal settings are used, PYTHONPATH affects any tools that
> are run within the terminal by a user, as well as any action the
> extension performs for a user that is routed through the terminal such
> as debugging. However, in this case when the extension is performing
> an action that isn't routed through the terminal, such as the use of a
> linter or formatter, then this setting will not have an effect on
> module look-up.
>
> When PYTHONPATH is set using an .env file, it will affect anything the
> extension does on your behalf and actions performed by the debugger,
> but it will not affect tools run in the terminal.
>
> If needed, you can set PYTHONPATH using both methods.
>
> An example of when to use PYTHONPATH would be if you have source code
> in a src folder and tests in a tests folder. When running tests,
> however, those tests can't normally access modules in src unless you
> hard-code relative paths.
>
> To solve this problem, you could add the path to src to PYTHONPATH by
> creating an .env file within your VS Code workspace.
>
> PYTHONPATH=src

[official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable)

Answer (score 0):

First, add `__init__.py` file inside the `rogers` folder.

Then, you need to add your project directory path to `sys.path` or `$PYTHONPATH`. Then only python can recognize the package and import it. This will definitely solve the problem.